# Computer switches between detecting TV and undetecting it, and chimes. How to stop this?

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, tv, hardware-detection

I have a Dell Optiplex 3070 micro with Intel UHD Graphics 630, connected to an old LG TV over HDMI. The OS is Windows 10 Pro. I keep the PC on, and when I switch the TV to an input that is different from the Dell, the computer starts to switch between recognizing the screen, and not recognizing it. It chimes as when new hardware is connected, and disconnected, which is rather annoying.

If I connect to the PC via a remote desktop, I see the resolution switching between 1024x768 to 1920x1080. Is there a way to lock the settings to 1920x1080, so that this would not happen?

Comment: The display is being uninstalled and reinstalled. You may be able to get around this by plugging the HDMI cable into a different port, if you plug it into one of the HDMI ports that have more features, such as CEC+ or audio return, this may be happening. Try one that doesn't.

Comment: The problem is not about "locking the resolution", the problem is likely a partially defective TV.

Comment: @ChanganAuto just because a tv does not behave desireably does not mean it is partially defective.

Comment: @LPChip Actually given the symptom a defect is likely. I have tested hundreds if not thousands of TVs for this usage over the years, many were LG and never noticed such problem when alternating sources.

Comment: And I've had this problem on ports that had more features but the problem went away when going to a port with less features. Was even possible to test it with 2 different TV's, but I've also had it not happen with other TV's, that's why its a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Could also be a dodgy cable.

Comment: @LPChip The TV has three HDMI ports. The computer detects the TV on two of them, and they both exhibit the same uninstall/intstall behavior. The PC won't detect the TV on the third port, sadly... I even tried to disable the CEC option on the TV, which they call SIMPLINK, but no luck.